# how to sum even and odd numbers of an array using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

i need help creating a recursive function that takes a list/array of numbers and returns a tuple or similar format `(a,b)` where `a` is sum of even numbers and `b` is sum of odd ones...
For example:

```
input: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 

return: (6, 9)
```

Comment: preferably python, but any language is fine :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python, you can try this:

```
def sum_even_odd(lst):
    if not lst:                      # empty list, we're done
        return (0, 0)                # counters are zero for empty list
    elif lst[0] % 2 == 0:            # current value is even
        x, y = sum_even_odd(lst[1:]) # recursive call
        return (lst[0] + x, y)       # increment even counter
    else:                            # current value is odd
        x, y = sum_even_odd(lst[1:]) # recursive call
        return (x, lst[0] + y)       # increment odd counter
```

Notice how the base case returns `(0, 0)`, and from that point on, each successive recursive call increments the right value in the tuple depending on the current value in the list, if it's even or odd. It works as expected:

```
sum_even_odd([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
=> (6, 9)
```

Comment: Oscar ty vm this was driving me nuts :-)