# Returning an Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989202/how-to-sum-even-and-odd-numbers-of-an-array-using-recursion?noredirect=1#19989202) to write a recursive function in JavaScript to add elements of an array and return an array accordingly.

in Pseudocode

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
func (arr,2) = > [1+3+5, 2+4+6]
                 [9,12]
func (arr,3) = > [1+4,2+5,3+6]
                 [5,7,9]
```

So I wrote a fiddle, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/W4vmW/2/).

```
var input = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

function tupleAdd(tuple,i,p,t,output){
    if(typeof t == "undefined")
        t=0;
    if(typeof p == "undefined")
        p=0;
    if(typeof output == "undefined")
        output = [];
    if(typeof output[t] =="undefined")
        output[t]=0;

    output[t]+=i[p];
    p++;
    t++;
    t>=tuple?t=0:null;
    if(p<i.length)
        tupleAdd(tuple,i,p,t,output);
    else{
        console.log(output);
        return(output);
    }
}

x = tupleAdd(3,input);
console.log(x);
```

My function works, as the first `console.log()` shows the appropriate values. What weirds me out is that when I `return` `output` (with or without parens), and try and log it again, I get `undefined`.

I find this deeply unsettling. Can anyone shed some light on why the `return` value is different than the `console.log` value?

Comment: What happens if you add `return` before the recursive call to `tupleAdd()`?

Comment: How about doing `return tupleAdd(tuple, i, p, t, output)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the value of the recursive call:

```
var input = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

function tupleAdd(tuple,i,p,t,output){
    if(typeof t == "undefined")
        t=0;
    if(typeof p == "undefined")
        p=0;
    if(typeof output == "undefined")
        output = [];
    if(typeof output[t] =="undefined")
        output[t]=0;

    output[t]+=i[p];
    p++;
    t++;
    t>=tuple?t=0:null;
    if(p<i.length)
        return tupleAdd(tuple,i,p,t,output);
    else{
        console.log(output);
        return(output);
    }
}

x = tupleAdd(3,input);
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your recursion is broken. You are getting undefined since you do not have a return on the function call inside.

```
tupleAdd(tuple,i,p,t,output);
```

needs to be

```
return tupleAdd(tuple,i,p,t,output);
```

Comment: Thank you! Upvoted you and Ben. I just accepted his because he was first to comment. I didn't have a better criteria, since both answers were equally helpful and came in at about the same time.

Answer (score -2):

```
function doTuple(arr, tuple){

    if(!arr.length){
        return tuple;
    }

    var el = arr.splice(0,1);

    el % 2 ? tuple.evens += +el : tuple.ods += +el;

    return doTuple(arr, tuple);
}

console.log(doTuple([1,2,3,4,5], {evens:0,ods:0}));
```